# When I am printing an Indesign file certain characters are not printing or printing looking like hieroglyphics?

Tags: print-design

I have tried printing from Indesign and it leaves out letters or changes them to some unknown characters.
I have also saved the file as a pdf then printed and I still have the same problems. Not only does it leave out letters it also changes the sequence of special characters, numbers, and letters in a sequence such as GW-1.  Most issues are from files created in Excel but not all is Excel created.

I have cleared cache file, restarted the program, and restarted my Mac to no avail.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Sounds like a bad font file. This is really impossible to troubleshoot remotely, there are too many localized variables - the printer, your computer, the font...

Comment: When you say "files created in Excel", what file format are these files in?  Are you exporting PDFs from Excel?  What are your export settings?  Why are you using InDesign to print the files? What is GW-1?

Comment: Just to be clear: your indesign **and** PDF files *display* the proper glyphs, but fail to print them correctly? This used to be a problem with e.g. TTF and Type1 fonts used in the same document. Not sure if this is still a known issue in any modern software.